# Как вставить текст в скрытый textarea с помощью selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium-webdriver

День добрый.
Каким образом можно вставить текст в скрытый элемент `Textarea` с помощью `Selenium Webdriver`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim txtScript = String.Format("arguments[0].innerText = '{0}';", "texttexttext")
DirectCast(driver, IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript(txtScript, element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Что то типа этого (под жабу так)

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('inputId').value = 'My value';");
```

Или с помощью JS сделать элемент видимым и уже просто его в браузере обработать.